# Is missyar marriage with a non-Muslim permissible?

Tags: nikah

can we marry a non Muslim with misyar contract ? Is misyar even halal, cause i heard that some of the Islamic scholars said that it is forbidden.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please use meaningful question titles in order to attract those people who can actually answer your inquiry as I've tried to do by editing! Further your username may indicate that you are male, but it would be better to clarify from which perspective the question is asked in order to avoid confusion!

Comment: What is a Missyar marriage? Please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

> Shaykh Saalih Al-Fawzaan:
>
> We  do not advise  with it, because it is not in line with the  good
> interest of an Islamic marriage. Rather it is merely fulfilling the
> desires. And he will not have authority over his wife, and she will
> not live with him in his home. And if they have children they will be
> far away from him and from his supervision. Thus the intent behind
> marriage will not be achieved. Therefore e we do not advise with it.

[The Ruling on Misyaar Marriage – Shaykh Saalih Al-Fawzaan](https://abdurrahman.org/2015/08/11/the-ruling-on-misyaar-marriage/)

Comment: but is it haram ?

Comment: It is not haram if the marriage contract fulfils all the conditions set out by sharee’ah, which is the presence of the wali and the consent of both partners, and the presence of two witnesses of good character to the drawing up of the contract.

Comment: so I can marry for example non muslim women(Jewish and Christian) with misyaar contract ?

Comment: I am not qualified to issue such a fatwa. Please consult a scholar

Comment: alright, thanks anyway.May Allah bless you.